# django-ckeditor change upload path prefix

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I want to change the prefix of upload path in django-ckeditor. By default it generates subdirectories by using username and date so something like:

```
/media/uploads/username/year/month/day/uploaded_file
```

The documentation says:

> Set the `CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER` setting to `True` in the project’s settings.py file (default False). This restricts access to uploaded images to the uploading user (e.g. each user only sees and uploads their own images). Upload paths are prefixed by the string returned by `get_username`. If `CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER` is set to a string, the named property is used instead.

After few tries, still can't figure out how to configure this to handle prefix of uploaded files.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set **CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True** in your **settings.py** file.
The upload path will be /media/uploads/username/year/month/day/uploaded_file as you desired.

Ckeditor processes the user path using following view. https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor_uploader/views.py